# Manually pass 1 out of 3 generics and tell compiler to infer the rest

Tags: typescript

I have function with 3 generics:

```ts
function createAPIAction<
  OwnArgs extends unknown[], 
  Type extends string, 
  Payload
>(
    type: Type, 
    bb: (...args: [...OwnArgs, number, string]) => Payload
) {
    return (...c: OwnArgs) => {
        return (a: number, b: string) => ({ 
            type, 
            payload: bb(...c, a, b) 
        });
    }
}

// gives error
const actionCreator = createAPIAction(
    'a', 
    (c: symbol, a, b) => ({ a, b, c })
);

// and this gives error too :(
const actionCreator2 = createAPIAction<symbol>(
    'a', 
    (c, a, b) => ({ a, b, c })
);
```

See also [interactive Playground on TS website](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQQQAoCSO08YAPAFCKIDyA7mDigOYDOiaAHtmACbvgA1mDgMA2gF0ANIiqIAKgE8ADmg7c0fdqygoYYZjLl4MigDZwMvCgD4AFHOpQVaAFwKXR6tQBGP93YAdMEYLKzuYsGB9IxhMmAgALY%20aCgyOnoGEgCUiAC8Nogm5pbWuQDejojoUCAoSEHBEO4xTGy5BYiV3j3VaLX1iHYY7gnJqTL%20iBn6zB2FduWyvSuIzqpeqz3KphZW7n6NgRAyGJO5VT0AvtkA3FVXFI8UAPQviMwwAG5o7KkocBQFAgCB0iAwJAQAGF0FhAflkLDsPgiJCwA4egByDCYzbUOzNaaKZJwMync75BZLM6IHwyCCIG4UO4UV7vDB8NYACxg7E%20Pz%20KABKDWcDgiFcDhBYDBENg0KRgIATAjUJhkYRiPLyKxiT5SfYqtjcctvATybT5kNqZN6YzsszbkA)

Is there way to define `OwnArgs` generic, but infer others from a call? (preferably without changing function implementation, just typings)

P.S.

Got it working for 1 argument, see [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQQQAoCSO08YAPAFCKIDyA7mDigOYDOANIlYgCoCeABzSI0AD2xgAJq0SsoKGGGadueDHwA2cDJIoA%20ABTdqUQWgBcvMyurUARncsGAdK4wtWlgNr1GHzmAgALZ2aCiccgpKALoAlIgAvHqIaprauvEA3saI6FAgKEgGEJa%20TGzxSYjZtrW5aPmFiAYYloEhYZyOsvKKzJXJBplcdaOIpkI2Y7UC6lo6lg7FnBhd8Tm1AL6xANw5mxQHFAD0x4h86gCEiDBQiHRwKADWrBQQCHKIGCQIAMLoWEeiWQAOw%20CIPzARlqAHIMDCptRipZWHwQnANCs1olBsNVog7JwIIhthRdhQTmdzEZ3mBPt9YH9QY8AEzA1CYMGEYiMqE5OEIka2ZGyNF2DGcSQo3pKLEEgbNPFdIkk2JknZAA) . But how to extend it for 2 (or 3) arguments?

Comment: github issue about this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571

Answer (score 1):

I tried to follow the type names a little bit, and came up with this. Usually I avoid defining generics as an array as a rule of thumb. Let me know if this solution works.

```
function createAPIAction<
  OwnArgs extends unknown, 
  Type extends string, 
  Payload
>(
    type: Type, 
    bb: (...args: [number, string, ...Array<OwnArgs>]) => Payload
) {
    return (...c: Array<OwnArgs>) => {
        return (a: number, b: string) => ({ 
            type, 
            payload: bb(a, b, ...c) 
        });
    }
}

// Works now
const actionCreator = createAPIAction(
    'a', 
    (a, b, c: symbol) => ({ a, b, c })
);
```

Comment: No, it assumes only 1 type and reverse order, see [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQQQAoCSO08YAPAFCKIDyA7mDigOYDOiaAHtmACbvgA1mDgMANIiqIAKgE8ADmg7c0fdqygoYYZhKl4MsgDZwMvCgD4AFFOpQFaAFwyHe6tQBGH51YB0-jBZWZwBtMBAAWw80FAkNLR0Jf18mFEMyekYgiwBdAEpEAF4LRANjU3MCgG9bRHQoEBQkP38IZ1T0zKY2CwLixBr3Ibq0BqbEKwxncKiYiW9EeO1mPpKrKslhrcR7RTdtoflDEzNnL0n5pNaC2qGAXzyAblq7ileKAHoPxAB1OBRBOwRHQKBAEBpEBgSAgAMLoLD-IrIeHYfBEaFgGxDADkGGx+2oF0QHgkbUWsiicCMqwmGwwl2QiAeFCeFE+3xiKH+oPBUEhGLhmCg-wATEjUELcIRiLAEFj3Lj8Zt3ESSchnKwKR4qRJeBrNMsaetIQyILqmXkWc8gA)

Comment: Try this:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQQQAoCSO08YAPAFCKIAqAngA5qJoAe2YAJgM6LdQoYYAOYAaRFUR4MdADZwMnCgD4AFJOpRGaAFy1t4jYgBGxvaox6wIALbG0KcWb4ChYxADov6fnpwoUGTIMMDplAEpEAF5lKRl5RQpIgG8jdCgQFCRVLw8IPwCgkLDImMRU6krK9Mzsy0RrOwcnPX5BEVLY1WSJKr7KrSZDfv6GeIVOPVMLJ3FciEijKoBfcIBuI2WKLYoAel3EAHU4FABrXjA4AHcKCAR+RAwSBABhdCwT6OR37HwiZ7A6iqAHIMMDhpUZiZxPk+HQ7HBZJ1EN1HrNkIhVkkNnsDsczhdrrd7lBHgC3pgoCcAExfVCU3CEYiwBBAyqg8G9SEYdGw7jw4yI8STFztYTI1E86HIYWY8LYihAA

Comment: Yeah, it works! But also requires to "reverse" arguments which will result in a lot of manual refactoring of old code. Would like to do it without rewriting, just by adding types